# Program executes when being set to a variable

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create a script to check if a program (In this case, the calculator) is running or not.
I also don't quite understand why `set oExec = script.Exec("calc")` would run the program. Thanks in advance :)

```
set script = wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set oExec = script.Exec("calc")

Do While oExec.Status = 0
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

if oExec.Status = 1 Then
    MsgBox("Calculator is open")
    WScript.Quit()
End if
```

Comment: Because that's exactly [what the `Exec()` function does](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/5593b353-ef4b-4c99-8ae1-f963bac48929.asp)?  I guess it's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to so just set scrpt.exec("calc") to a variable but not running it when its not called.If that makes it clearer

Comment: Calling a function calls that function.  What exactly are you expecting to be in that variable?  How are you planning to use that variable?  Currently the shown use of that variable expects a running program.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Is there a way to check the status of a program(calc) without opening the program(calc)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a process is running using VB script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32963635/how-to-check-whether-a-process-is-running-using-vb-script)

Comment: I already solved my problem shown down below. But thanks anyways

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run loop check vbs for particular running process? Or missing process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688202/how-to-run-loop-check-vbs-for-particular-running-process-or-missing-process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem! From this:  [How to run loop check vbs for particular running process? Or missing process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45688202/how-to-run-loop-check-vbs-for-particular-running-process-or-missing-process)

```
Set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")

For Each Process In Service.InstancesOf("Win32_Process")
    If Process.Name = "Calculator.exe" Then
        WScript.Echo "Calc is running"
        WScript.Quit
    End If
Next
```

Comment: In which case flag it as a duplicate.